# error C3861: 'strcpy': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

why I am I getting this error?

*EDIT I posted my solution at the bottom. It turns out that I wasn't able to use strcpy() in a particular section of my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution that worked for  me. if you are having issues like I did with strcpy,  you can use size() to figure out the size of the string and then use a while loop to go through and add it to the char array. this is what eventually worked for me :

let's say we have a data structure member with a char array data.name[30] and we have two words in the file that make up the name (first and last) and we can't just add it to the char array with strcpy. We also can't use string stream because it loses the last name in the process. the text in the file includes fields separated by delimiters # (with exception to the last field which ends with  a newline. for the name field I used this:

```
/* we already declared an ifstream inputFile and opened it. */
while(!inputFile.eof())
{
    string temp;
    getline(inputFile, temp, '#');
    int size=temp.size();
    int i=0;
    while (i<size)
    {
       data.name[i]=temp[i];
       i++;
    }      
}

data.name[i]=0;
inputFile.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean `strcpy()`? There is no standard function called `strcopy()` that I know of. Also, if you are using C++, then if possible, use `std::string` instead since this will handle copying and other string manipulation for you.

Comment: error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'

Comment: @user1066524 : You should be using `std::string` _instead of_ `strcpy` and `char*`, not in conjunction with.

Comment: @user1066524: post your full code so we can see what you're trying to do. Otherwise, at least try `strcpy(destination, str.c_str())` if the second parameter is a `std::string` and the first parameter is of `char[]` or `char*` type. Ideally, you should not be using `strcpy` at all and just using `std::string`.

Comment: string temp;    and data structure member char array data.name. i'm trying to copy this temp string holding the last name into the char name array.         strcpy(data.name, temp);

Comment: @user1066524: In that case, try `strcpy(data.name, temp.c_str());`.

Comment: i tried and it won't work. the method has these parameters         void loadCustomers(Account &data, std::ifstream& customerFile){ and so data.name already holds the first name. i am simply trying to append the last name that I got from the file I opened.

Comment: @user1066524: What do you mean by "it doesn't work". If you want to *append* to the string, you have to use `strcat` not `strcpy`. Or rather, if it is available, use `strncat`. If `data.name` truly is a char array and not a char pointer, then you can use `strncat(data.name, temp.c_str(), sizeof(data.name));`